# ACF: get_field() returning false

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom true/false field with the default value of true. I've set different posts to different values. However, get_field() always returns false:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
            <?php global var_dump(get_field('display_featured_image'));?>
<?php endwhile; endif ?>
```

The displayed output is: (bool)false

I've checked and double checked the field name. Why would it return false if the value is set to true?

Comment: I've noticed that the True/False fields don't seem to honor a `true` default value outside of initializing the UI: the box will be checked for posts that don't have a value yet, but until you actually *save* the post the `true` value is not saved to the DB. If you `get_field()` on a post with nothing saved to the DB, it will return `false` (regardless of the field's default value). I'd call this a bug but haven't reported it, pending more investigation.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass in the ID of the post you're trying to get the field from: Eg

```
get_field('display_featured_image', $post_id).
```

In a loop you could do

```
get_field('display_featured_image', get_the_id());
```

ACF Stores field data in wp's meta_fields, so you could even use WP's built in meta handler to pull the data yourself Eg:

```
get_post_meta( $post_id, 'acf_field_name', true); // Use true for almost every case, as WP will return an array otherwise.
```

Comment: I've tried get_field (with and without ID) and get_post_meta -- both within the loop -- but still nothing.

Comment: I've tried debugging with: ` print_r(get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'display_featured_image'));` ...and now I'm not at all sure what's happening. When I try a post that has the field set to false, the output is `Array ( [0] => 0 )` but when I load a post that has the field set to true, the output is just: `Array ( )`

Comment: Are you perhaps setting the field backwards? Eg, when you're selecting "display_featured_image" in the post editor, are you setting it to "true" when selected and "false" when not? Because it seems like the field IS getting data, you might just be doing it backwards.

Try setting the select field in the ACF editor to 

Yes : Yes
No : No

And see what comes when you get the field data again.

Comment: I have an idea of what's going on. I changed the field type to select but was still getting the same results. However, even though the field has a default value, I have to set this explicitly in the existing posts for any value to be stored. Arghh! Looks like there's no work around for that either, unless you know any different?

Comment: No, based on what your question said, it should be working. Is the state of the field in the post editor being retained? Eg: If you set it to 1 or the other, does the setting persist on reload? If so, then there's no reason it's not working.

Comment: Yes the state is being retained but I've discovered that if I add a field to existing posts, the state won't be stored, no matter whether the field has a default value, until I've explicitly set that value. Hence the empty array.

Comment: It may be worth noting, that for some reason, using update_field programatically will NOT actually update the field until the form is saved for the first time.  It has to do with how the field data is initially populated by ACF. You can use WP's native update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value ); to bypass this issue. This is referred to in acf's documentation. I myself came across this issue during a project and tore my hair out for hours before I figured this out by scouring ACF's documentation :P

Comment: There is also a "bug" when you call the get_field() with field name and then with field key - it returns different values

Comment: I had this problem then I released I was passing in `->ID` which matched the page menu ID and not he id of the page. Instead I needed to use `->object_ID`. This was using `wp_get_nav_menu_object()`

Answer (score -1):

You have a few options. The easiest would be to use `get_field( $field_key )` (use the ACF field ID rather than the meta_key). This will choose the correct field regardless of location rules which will let it access the default value.

If you must use the meta key, you can mostly do so with filters. Not sure how efficient it is (could be mitigated by using acf-json caching). This also assumes that your fields keys are unique (otherwise you have to filter based on the location rules, which may or may not be available).

```
add_filter( 'acf/load_value', function( $value, $post_id, $field ){
    // get your field groups
    $groups = acf_get_field_groups();
    if ( !empty( $groups ) ){
        // loop over each group
        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            // load the fields for this group key
            $fields = acf_get_fields( $group['key'] );
            if ( !empty( $fields ) ){
                // loop over the returned fields
                foreach ( $fields as $this_field ){
                    // if the name is a match, set the default value
                    if ( $this_field['name'] == $field['name'] ){
                        return $this_field['default_value'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```